# I have an idea for a clothing concept. How I can mock my design so I can improve it?

Tags: sewing

I though an idea for some clothes, but I want to see whether my idea is looking good or not and create the rough sketch.

I made some rough doodles/sketches about my idea but I want to see if this idea actually looks good. Would using paper and some sort of a doll will suffice?

Should I switch into cheap fabric, what I actually want it to prototype it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the term "mockup" or short "mock" is what you're looking for. In fashion design it is a test version of a garment made from cheaper fabric.

Using paper for a mockup doesn't work, unless the final fabric should be stiff and inflexible like paper. You cannot see how a garment shapes itself around the body of a wearer if the material you use for the mockup cannot do that. You should use a fabric for the mockup that behaves at least mostly like the fabric you plan on using for the final garment in terms of elasticity and drape.

There are dress forms / dressmaker's dummies half the size of a real person. These are often used in fashion design schools to test out ideas with less fabric than would be needed for a full-sized human. However, if you go too small (like <sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> human size or smaller) the fabric behaves differently. Drape is heavily influenced by the weight of the actual piece of fabric, so a small piece for a small mockup folds an hangs completely different from a doll than a full-sized piece from a real human.

Comment: Should I be looking for these type of dolls? https://tinyurl.com/yz2m4ndu

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas No, they are *tiny*! Just as big as a hand. You can use them for decoration, but not for checking how real fabric influences the look of a garment.

Comment: For rough/early mockups, you *can* actually use paper, or more specifically, certain cloth-like brands of paper towels (Viva is a good one for this). It doesn't get you to the drape of the fabrics you're using, but it does let you get the basic shapes worked out quickly in smaller scales.

Comment: Additionally, down around 1/3 scale you still have a good replica of how fabric will behave on a human at a much smaller size. At 1/4, thicker fabrics will lose draping, but a lot of fine ones will even behave here. I've even gotten good results with a double-layer of garment linen at 1/4 scale.